# Enviar o formulário para endereços diferentes conforme CEP

Tags: php, javascript, formulário, if

Tenho um formulário que calcula a taxa de entrega conforme o CEP, até aí tudo funcionando 100%. Meu cliente esta abrindo o seu negócio em outra área e quer que os pedidos sejam enviados conforme a área.

Hoje todos os pedidos são enviados para um único e-mail, pedido@restaurante.com.br, agora com o novo restaurante em copacabana ele quer que os pedidos feitos com o CEP de copacabana, seja enviado para o e-mail pedidocopa@restaurante.com.br. Como posso fazer isso?

Segue o código do arquivo mail.php

```
   <?

// Verifica se contagem.php existe
/* Se for a primeira vez que executa ele não irá existir. */
if( file_exists('contagem.php')){
    // Se existir inclui a variavel que armazena a informação
    include('contagem.php');
}

// Salva o proximo número no contagem.php (apagando a informação anterior e salvando o proximo número).
file_put_contents('contagem.php', '<?php $contagem='.((int)$contagem+1).' ?>');

// Exibe o $gerador que é igual a $contagem.
/* Remova o echo para ocultar obviamente */
echo $gerador = (int)$contagem;

?> 

<?php
include "login_senha.php";

$login = $_SESSION['login_usuario'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $nome = $linha['nome'];
    $endereco = $linha['endereco'];
    $cep = $linha['cep'];
    $telefone = $linha['telefone'];
    $email = $linha['email'];
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Agora = date('H:i:s');
$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));


if ( $Agora < '11:00:00'){
    $HoraServico = '12:00:00';
}

else if ( $Agora > '11:00:00' ){
    $HoraServico == $HoraServico;

};

$m = $_POST["mensagem"];
$data = $_POST["data"];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$pagamento = $_POST["pagamento"];
$troco = $_POST["troco"];
$mtotal = $_POST["mtotal"];
$nop = $_POST["nop"];
$op = $_POST["op"];
$obsfruta = $_POST["obsfruta"];
$quentes = $_POST["quentes"];
$molhos = $_POST["molhos"];
$embalagem = $_POST["embalagem"];
$saladas = $_POST["saladas"];
$sopas = $_POST["sopas"];
$sobremesas = $_POST["sobremesas"];
$sucos = $_POST["sucos"];
$bebidas = $_POST["bebidas"];
$emporio = $_POST["emporio"];
$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"];

$message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Bardana</title>';

$message .= '<style type="text/css">body, #bodyTable{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;}table{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;}img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;height:auto; line-height:100%;}a{text-decoration:none !important;}.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;}.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;}table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}#outlook a{padding:0;}img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display:block;outline:none; text-decoration:none;}body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-weight:normal!important;}.ExternalClass td[class="ecxflexibleContainerBox"] h3 {padding-top: 10px !important;}</style>';

$message .= '</head><body bgcolor="#EEEEEE" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0"><center style="background-color:#EEEEEE;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell"><table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><tr><td background="http://www.bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/centro.jpg" width="650" height="100" valign="top" align="center" style="color:#82b344;font-size:18px;"><img src="http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/toponovo.jpg" alt="Bardana" width="650" height="99" /></td></tr><tr>
  <td background="http://www.bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/centro.jpg" width="650" height="100" valign="top" align="center" style="color:#000000;font-size:10px;">
</p><p><a href="http://bardananatural.com.br/pesquisa-de-satisfacao/" target="new"><img src="http://www.bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/bot-pesquisa.jpg" alt="Bardana" width="650" height="100" /></a>*Responda n<span style="font-weight: normal">oss</span>a pesquisa e <span style="font-weight: 600">RECEBA 5%</span> <span style="font-weight: 700">de desconto</span>  no seu proximo pedido!!<tr><td width="650" height="10"></td></tr></p><tr><td width="325" style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal; color: #82b344; font-size: 11px;"><strong>Pedido feito em ';

$message .= $data;

$message .= '</strong></td></tr></head><body bgcolor="#EEEEEE" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0"><center style="background-color:#EEEEEE;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell"><table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><tr><td width="325" height="10" valign="top" align="center" style="color:#1361D9;font-size:14px;"><strong>Número do Pedido: 00';

$message .= $gerador;


$message .= '</head><tr><td width="650" height="10"></td></tr><body bgcolor="#EEEEEE" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0"><center style="background-color:#EEEEEE;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell"><table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><tr><td width="650" height="14" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" style="color:#000;font-size:10px;"><br><strong>Prazo limite para entrega:  ';

$message .= $HoraServico;

$message .= '</strong><br /><br /></td></tr><tr><td background="http://www.bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/centro.jpg" width="650" valign="top" align="center"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;">';

$message .= '<tr><td width="295" height="20" valign="top" align="left"></td></tr><tr><td width="295" height="100" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p><strong>Endereço: </strong>' . $endereco . '</p><p><strong>CEP: </strong>' . $cep . '</p><p><strong>Forma de Pagamento: </strong><br />' . $pagamento . '</p><p><strong>Precisa de troco?: </strong><br />' . $troco . '</p></td><td width="295" height="100" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"><p><strong>Nome: </strong>' . $nome . '</p><p><strong>Telefone: </strong>' . $telefone . '</p><p><strong>E-mail: </strong>' . $email . '</p><p><strong>Total do seu pedido: </strong>R$ ' . $mtotal . '</p><p><strong>A Taxa de Entrega: </strong>R$ ' . $entrega . '
</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" width="295" height="3" bgcolor="#82b344" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></td></tr><tr><td width="295" height="40" valign="middle" align="left" style="color:#82b344;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p><strong>Escolha a sua opção: </strong></p></td><td width="295" height="40" valign="middle" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"><p>' . $nop . $op . '</p></td></tr>';

$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2" width="293" height="3" border="1" bgcolor="#82b344" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></td></tr><tr><td width="293" height="40" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" valign="top" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Pratos quentes:</strong></p>' . $quentes . '<br /><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Molhos escolhidos:</strong></p>' . $molhos . '<br /></td><td width="293" height="40" valign="top" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#D7D7D7" border="1" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Saladas:</strong></p>' . $saladas . '<br /><p><strong>Observações:</strong>' . $obsfruta . '<p><strong>' . $embalagem . '</strong></td></tr></p>';

$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2" width="293" height="3" border="1" bgcolor="#82b344" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></td></tr><tr><td width="293" height="40" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#D7D7D7" valign="top" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Sopa do Dia:</strong></p>' . $sopas . '<br /></td><td width="293" height="40" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="1" valign="top" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Sobremesas:</strong></p>' . $sobremesas . '<br /></td></tr>';

$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2" width="293" height="3" border="1" bgcolor="#82b344" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></td></tr><tr><td width="293" height="40" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" valign="top" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Sucos:</strong></p>' . $sucos . '<br /></td><td width="293" height="40" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#D7D7D7" valign="top" align="left" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Bebidas:</strong></p>' . $bebidas . '<br /></td></tr>';

$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2" width="293" height="3" border="1" bgcolor="#82b344" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" width="293" height="40" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="1" style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-size:12px;"><p style="color:#82b344;"><strong>Nosso Empório:</strong></p>' . $emporio . '<br /></td></tr>';

$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2" width="295" height="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#82b344" style="line-height: 15px; font-size: 10px;">Obrigado pela sua preferência. Seu pedido vai chegar rapidinho!<br /><a href="www.bardananatural.com.br">www.bardananatural.com.br</a> | <strong>21. 2292-9232 | 2220-0334</strong></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td background="http://www.bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/centro.jpg" width="650" height="50" valign="top" align="center"><img src="http://bardananatural.com.br/pedido_online/images/rodape.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="50" /></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></center></body></html>';

$to = $email;
$subject = "Seu pedido ao restaurante BARDANA - Número do Pedido: 00" .$gerador;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: <pedido@bardananatural.com.br>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: pedido@bardananatural.com.br' . "\r\n";

//mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  echo "Seu pedido foi enviado com sucesso.<br>Você está recebendo uma cópia no endereço de e-mail que foi fornecido.<br><br>Obs.: Se você não receber a cópia do seu pedido em 10 minutos,<br>cheque a sua caixa de SPAM ou ligue para 2292-9232 | 2295-0334<br><br>";
}else{
  echo "Algo saiu errado no envio do seu pedido.<br>Por favor, ligue para 2292-9232 | 2295-0334<br><br>";
}

echo "<input type='button' id='voltar' class='botao' value=' VOLTAR ' onClick='location.replace(\"" . "http://bardananatural.com.br/" . "\");'>";
?>
```

O arquivo que faz o calcula das taxas é um form.js não sei se precisaria olhar o código desse arquivo também, precisando só avisar que coloco.

Comment: Cria uma tabela com os *ranges* de CEP e o email para onde quer mandar

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção! Amigo, sou leigo, consegui desenvolver esse formulário só deus sabe como. Se puder me passar o caminho das pedras eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça uma pequena modificação nesta parte do seu código:

```
$headers .= 'From: <pedido@bardananatural.com.br>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: pedido@bardananatural.com.br' . "\r\n";
```

No lugar do trecho acima, vai criar uma array com os ceps de copacabana, e ver se o cep é da região, se sim, envia para o email de lá, se não, envia e email como enviava antes:

```
//coloque os ceps que deseja enviar pra copacabana 
$ceps = array('80000-000','10000-000','20000-000');
if(in_array($cep,$ceps)){
   $headers .= 'From: <novoemail@bardananatural.com.br>' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Cc: novoemail@bardananatural.com.br' . "\r\n";
}else{
   $headers .= 'From: <pedido@bardananatural.com.br>' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Cc: pedido@bardananatural.com.br' . "\r\n";
}
```

Isso ja deve resolver.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!! Resolveu mesmo